# Swift Machine Learning Observation Not working

Tags: swift, machine-learning, uiview

I have an app that uses Machine learning to classify what an object is. 
My problem is that the text classifier is not working. Please disregard the structure of the code

```
  let classifierText: UILabel = {
    let classifer = UILabel()
    classifer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    classifer.textColor = .black
    classifer.font = UIFont(name: "Times-New-Roman", size: 10)
    classifer.textAlignment = .center
    return classifer
}()  func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
 guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
    guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Inceptionv3().model) else { return }
    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (finishedReq, err) in
    guard let results = finishedReq.results as?  [VNClassificationObservation] else { return }
    guard let firstObservation = results.first else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.classifierText.text = "This appears to be a \(firstObservation.identifier)"
     }
  }
    try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])
  }  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let theView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.frame = view.bounds
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        view.layer.borderWidth = 1
        view.addSubview(classifierText)
        return view
    }()
```

I fixed it. Here's the solution.

let dataOuput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOuput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
        imageSession.addOutput(dataOuput)

Comment: I fixed it. Here's the solution let dataOuput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOuput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
        imageSession.addOutput(dataOuput)

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question you should post it as an answer and accept it to help other people know that this question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Heres the solution.

let dataOuput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput() dataOuput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue")) 
imageSession.addOutput(dataOuput)